# How to not publish an APK to a specific Android Version?

Tags: android, google-play

My app is crashing on Android 8.1 but not on 8.0 and 9.0.
So, until I found a solution I want to make my app **not available** to **8.1 ONLY** users.

How can I achieve that?

This is my current (top part) gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.denox.mydenox.v2"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Comment: Do not post images of code, error messages, or other text. Copy and paste text into the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do these things:

- Restrict users from some device's types installing your apps: this can be done in your `Play Console`.
- Choose the `min` and the `max sdk version` for your app (only users having `sdk` versions between your gap can install your app): this can be done using `minSdkVersion` and `maxSdkVersion`.

There is no option called custom supported version. You have to have a trade-off if you want to exclude a specific supported android version. So my recommend would be you set your `minSdkVersion` to above 8.1.